# How to star github gists using github api?

Tags: rest, api, github, github-api

I'm trying to star a gist in my repo dynamically using the **github api v3** but i've stumbled on an error.

Here's the code.

```
fetch(
      `https://api.github.com/gists/${gistId}/star`,
      {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token}`,
          "Content-Length": "0"
        }
      }
    ).then(res => console.log({ res }));
```

It returns an error in this format w/c is pretty vague

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#star-a-gist"
}
```

Why do i have this error, when i already have passed the correct headers and token?

Comment: Try this in something like Postman first, passing the same variables for `gistId` and `token`, see if that works - this will narrow down the root of the problem. Perhaps the `gistId` is not being populated?  Likewise with `token`

Comment: @nopassport1 yup, i've already tried using constants but still no luck.

Comment: So the request works fine in Postman? In that case it's something to do with the way you're sending the `PUT` request.

Comment: @nopassport1 yeah, i have no clue what's the problem.

Comment: Should `Authorization` & `token` be wrapped in speech marks? Do you have `token` as part of your `token` variable?

Comment: @nopassport1 just found out the issue. I forgot to prepend the value of `Authorization` header with "token" 

so the value of of `Authorization` should be `token TOKEN_VALUE`.

And it seems like my token is expired or something, so i used another token and now it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad you solved it. I am a little perplexed as to how it worked in Postman without your 'token' in `token TOKEN_VALUE` though..

Comment: @nopassport1 it was included in the Postman, i just forgot to add it in the code. Just some sloppy mistake hehe.